# How to create a bundle using gulp without using "require" everywhere

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bundle, browserify

Thanks for reading. I am new to gulp, so apologizing if its a dumb question. I have an AngularJS project with the following folder structure:

```
app/
 app.js
 modules/
  mod1/
   index.js
   mod1.js
   another.js
  mod2/
    ... same structure as mod1
```

To create a bundle using browserify I am using this:

```
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
  return browserify('app/app.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(vinylSource('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

To make this work, I have include require('mod1') ..require('another') and so on.

I always have to make sure that I am requiring the script that I need to use.

My goal is to create a bundle that includes all javascript file inside my app folder starting from app.js without getting into dependency conflicts and without me writing require('somefile').

Answer (score 1):

You can get that by just using the gulp-concat plugin.

You just specify the paths to search.  Because you're using angular and need the modules defined before everything else, I'd add the app first, then all the module definitions, then remaining directives and controllers etc after.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('app-js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
      './app/app.js',
      './app/**/mod*.js',
      './app/**/*.js',
    ])
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
});
```